# Trigger browser file download on a bytestream

Tags: php, sockets, zend-framework, browser, download

we have an application server in Java, and a webclient in PHP.

We'd like to transfer a file from the Java server to the client in an user friendly way.

Is it possible to trigger the file download in the browser, using the stream that is sent from the Java server ?

The communication pass through sockets, if that can help.

Here's what I tried on the client side, using Zend Framework.

The view:

```
<?php 
        $file = $this->filename;
        $filesize = $this->filesize;

      header("Content-type: application/octet-stream\r\n");

      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"\r\n');
      header("Content-Length:$filesize\r\n");
      header("Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n");
      header("Cache-Control: private\n\n");
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
      header("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n");
      ob_clean();
      flush();
      $authNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Cubbyhole_SockLoader');
      $cl = $authNamespace->CoreLinker;
      $cl->downloadFile($this->fileId, "echo", $this->filesize);
?>
```

> $cl->downloadFile($this->fileId, "echo", $this->filesize);

read the datastream and echo what is received until the length of the file is outputed, and stop.

The problem is, as it could be expected, that before triggering the download, the whole file has to be echoed, causing time-outs PHP side, or just a really long loading page.
And then, when the file is echoed on the client side, the client has to download the file himself, which is not really optimised.

Is there a way to asynchronously send the data to the user's browser using PHP and the datastream coming out the socket ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was kinda simple.

I needed to explicitely say that the output buffering ended after sending the header, for the browser to take the stream as a download source.

```
<?php 
        $file = $this->filename;
        $filesize = $this->filesize;

      header("Content-type: application/octet-stream\r\n");

      header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"\r\n');
      header("Content-Length:$filesize\r\n");
      header("Accept-Ranges: bytes\r\n");
      header("Cache-Control: private\n\n");
      header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
      header("Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n");
      ob_clean();
      flush();
      ob_end_flush();//here
      $authNamespace = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Cubbyhole_SockLoader');
      $cl = $authNamespace->CoreLinker;
      $cl->downloadFile($this->fileId, "echo", $this->filesize);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should have a look at:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.advanced.html#zend.http.client.streaming

and

[Possible to download a file through the Zend HTTP Client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173390/possible-to-download-a-file-through-the-zend-http-client)

Also take a look at streaming in php ad the various **I/O Stream Wrappers** like 
**php://stdin**, **php://stdout** and **php://stderr** here:
http://www.php.net/manual/de/wrappers.php.php

You are currently working with a filename, which represents a stored file on your drive.

What you need to do is, request the file from your php webclient.

So your Java Server should respond to your webclient, sending a file as response.

Your **Zend Controller Action** should use some client to interact with your Java Server.

If your Java Server is listening on HTTP requests, use sth like Zend_Http_Client to get the response.

```
Browser -> Webclient -> Java Server
```

Both, the Webclient and the Java Server need to be able to stream data.

What you would do is, if a Browser requests a URI from your Webclient, the Controller Action that is called will request the fle as a stream from the Java Server.

The Webclient will get the php stream and proxy (forward) the file - bit by bit.

There are several techniques that can be used, so ask a more detailed question and I will try to answer it, if I can.

Have fun!

Comment: Thing is the Java server is an application server listening to sockets, and does not listen on http request, hence the problem. But I've found the solution thought.